# $PHP_AUTOCONF errors on mac os x 10.7.3 when trying to install pecl extensions

Tags: mac-osx, php5, pecl, zend-server-ce

I am trying to setup my machine with pecl_http and memcache and in both cases, I get similar errors. This is on MAC OS X 10.7.3 (lion) and I also have XCODE installed on it. I also installed Zend Server community edition before running these commands and have `CFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'` environment variables set

```
bash-3.2# **sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.1**
downloading pecl_http-1.7.1.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-1.7.1.tgz (174,098 bytes)
.....................................done: 174,098 bytes
71 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
**$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.**
**ERROR: `phpize' failed**
```

Answer (score 4):

Just install autoconf manually:

As per http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=125,

- Download the latest release http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
- Extract the files
- do a normal `./configure; make; sudo make install;`

Answer (score 0):

XCODE 4.3 doesn't put all the autoconf etc. tools in the Developer folder. It doesn't even create that folder in MACINTOSH HD. I had to downgrade to XCODE 4.2.1 which installs everything you need in the Developer folder and now I see no errors.

Also here is a useful reference : http://inessential.com/2012/02/17/everything_moved_in_xcode_4_3